# ALT Key Detection WebWorks/Desktop

Tags: javascript, html, keypress, blackberry-webworks

Ive wrote a simple function shown below..

```
function handleKeyPress(showEvent,formItem) {

 if(showEvent == null){}
else if(showEvent.keyCode == 13)
{
    var feildID = formItem.id;
    var pid=formItem.parentNode.id;

    var index = enterKeyForm[pid].indexOf(feildID);
    $('#' + enterKeyForm[pid][++index]).focus();
    console.log(index);


}
else(alert(showEvent.keyCode))
```

}

If i add this code to my page to my body tag

```
 onkeydown="javascript:getKeys(event);"
```

And add this function

```
function getKeys(event)
{
     if(event.altKey)
     {  alert("The Alt key was pressed!");}
}
```

This works in chrome but not blackberry...
I can capture alt+ anykey and shift+any key just not alt on its own..

This captures a key pressed well the user is on a form item, the parameters are the event and the form item , send yas onkeypress(event,this)?

But this does not fire an event for hte alt key in chrome or blackberry...
But fires for all other keys...

Im developing on webworks SDK.

Thanks